# Trying to change BattleState globally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm a completely new to coding and am trying to create a card game. I've watched some tutorials and tried to take things into my own hands but cant seem to figure out something. I currently have a BattleState set up;

public enum BattleState { START, PLAYERMAINPHASE, PLAYERBATTLEPHASE, PLAYERENCORESTEP, ENEMYTURN, WON, LOST }

and would like it so when i change the BattleState with a script, it changes it for every other script that references this BattleState. Sorry for the bad wording. Coding is rough :/

Comment: Is there a reason you would have it on multiple scripts? If this value is supposed to be the same everywhere then one instance of it is enough and the others can just directly reference it here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interfaces, create an interface such as IBattleStateChanger and have a method on it

```
interface IBattleStateChanger{
    void ChangeBattleState(YourClass.BattleState state);
}
```

Then on every script you want the value to change implement this interface as

```
ClassExample : IBattleStateChanger {}
```

This will then force you to create a method in the script to change the state

After that, whenever you want to change the value globally on the scripts where you implemented this interface, you can do a foreach loop finding each type of this interface such as

```
BattleState newState = BattleState.START;
foreach (var obj in FindObjectsOfType<IBattleStateChanger>){
      obj.SetBattleState(newState);
}
```

Comment: This is really simple and easy to understand. I'm going to give this a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Everytime using `FindObjectsOfType` is quite expensive though .. I would rather go the other way round and let the listeners register callbacks themselves

Answer (score 2):

You could use a static event and attach listeners/callbacks to it like e.g.

```
public enum BattleState
{
    START, PLAYERMAINPHASE, PLAYERBATTLEPHASE, PLAYERENCORESTEP, ENEMYTURN, WON, LOST
}

public static class BattleStateMgr
{       
    private static BattleState _state;

    public static BattleState State => _state;

    public static event System.Action<BattleState> OnStateChange;

    public static ChangeState(BattleState s)
    {
        _state = s;
        OnStateChange?.Invoke(_state);
    }
}

public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        BattleStateMgr.OnStateChagne += OnBattleStateChange;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        BattleStateMgr.OnStateChagne -= OnBattleStateChange;
    }

    private void OnBattleStateChange(BatlleState newState)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Changed Battle State to{newState}", this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was so free to refactor your code a bit how I think it improves the quality a lot, hope that's ok with you ;)

Comment: It's totally fine~

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confused about the scope of your variable. Each script you place an instance of the enum `Battlestate`, is a local version of that enum. If you want the reference to be global, you will need to have a central point where all scripts can grab this reference.

```
public class BattleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     private BattleState battleState;

     // setter / getters
     public BattleState GetBattleState(){return battleState; }
     public void SetBattleState(BattleState state){ battleState = state; } 
}
```

You are going to want to make a single script that holds the only reference to your enum `Battlestate`, then have your other scripts reference the variable.

```
public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
     // assign this reference in the inspector
     [SerializeField] private BattleManager bm = null;

     private void YourFunction()
     {
          if(bm.GetBattleState() == BattleState.randomStateHere)
          { 
                // run logic here
          }
     }
}
```

There are a number of ways to go about doing this, but the easiest would most likely be by declaring the variable `static`.

```
public class BattleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     private static BattleState battleState;

     // setter / getters
     public static BattleState GetBattleState(){return battleState; }
     public static void SetBattleState(BattleState state){ battleState = state; } 
}
```

```
public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void YourFunction()
     {
          if(BattleManager.GetBattleState() == BattleState.randomStateHere)
          { 
                // run logic here
          }
     }
}
```

I do not know how many scripts you need to access this variable, but if it is only a handful, I would instead assign references to the script that holds the enum to each of the scripts that need it. I would avoid simply using `static` as it is the easy approach but creates what is called a [`code smell`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). The reason for this is OOP (object-oriented programming) by design should generally not have mutable global variables.

If you have a single instance of an object that manages all of your battle activity and a lot of scripts need to access it, you can look into the [`Singleton`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) pattern. As you are new to programming, I would not implement this pattern until you understand the time and place to properly use it. You can also completely avoid using it by properly assigning the references you need in the inspector or by using a [`Object.FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) in either `Start` or `Awake`.

Comment: Using something `static` where it makes sense is not code smell. The Singleton Pattern (or at least abusing it the way you suggest by providing the single instance globally) however is even more controversial and code smell!  In this case I'd say a `static` class is totally fine since OP wants the value explicitly to be **global**. I would still rather go for event based instead of polling the state though

Comment: A good alternative though might be using a `ScriptableObject` and reference it everywhere where needed ;)